# Nested multi-bulk replies in Redis

Tags: redis

In the [redis protocol specification](http://redis.io/topics/protocol), under the "Multi-bulk replies section":

> A Multi bulk reply is used to return an array of other replies. Every element of a Multi Bulk Reply can be of any kind, including a nested Multi Bulk Reply.

However, I can't figure out a way to get Redis to return such output.  Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only certain commands (especially those returning list of values) return multi-bulk replies, you can try by using [`LRANGE`](http://redis.io/commands/lrange) for example but you can check the [command reference](http://redis.io/commands) for more details.

Usually multi-bulk replies are only 1-level deep but some Redis commands can return nested multi-bulk replies (max 2 levels), notably [`EXEC`](http://redis.io/commands/exec) (depending on the commands executed while inside the transaction context) and both [`EVAL`](http://redis.io/commands/eval) / [`EVALSHA`](http://redis.io/commands/evalsha) (depending on the value returned by the Lua script).

Here is an example using `EXEC`:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> MULTI
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> LPUSH metavars foo foobar hoge
QUEUED
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> LRANGE metavars 0 -1
QUEUED
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> EXEC
1) (integer) 4
2) 1) "hoge"
   2) "foobar"
   3) "foo"
   4) "metavars"
```

The second element of the multi-bulk reply to `EXEC` is a multi-bulk itsef.

**PS**: I added a clarification in the comments regarding the actual maximum level of nesting of multi-bulk replies when using Lua scripts. tl;dr: there's basically no limit.

Comment: Thanks for the example!  Since data structures are always flat (see [Redis data types](http://redis.io/topics/data-types)), I can rest assured that the reply parser doesn't need to handle unlimited nesting like a JSON parser would require.

Comment: Well that's true if you stick solely to the data types used by Redis, but if you are writing a parser (I missed your actual goal) then you **must** make it able to handle unlimited nesting because `EVAL` and `EVALSHA` actually can return user-created Lua tables unrelated to the data types, you can easily try this with `redis-cli` using the following command: `EVAL "return { { 1, { 2, { 3, { 4, { 5, { 6, { 7 } } } } } } } }" 0`. Note that `redis-cli` cannot handle more than 7-levels deep multi-bulk replies, while `hiredis` (the official C client library) has an hard-coded limit of 10 levels.